# breeze- custom handling of properties with concurrency-mode = fixed

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

Our existing entity framework back-end has custom logic for handling properties with concurrency-mode = fixed.  The standard breeze logic for assigning these properties interferes with this logic.

What is the best way to customize or skip the logic in the updateConcurrencyProperty method that is called when saving changes?

Any ideas/hacks welcome.  I could always modify the breeze source if there's no way to change the behavior programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible options

1. change the EF concurrency mode to 'None'
2. Hack the entityType in question and set it's concurrencyProperties to an empty array

   > ```
   > var fooEntityType = myEntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Foo");   
   > fooEntityType.concurrencyProperties = [];
   > ```

No guarantee if you try #2, (because it's only a partial fix) but if it works please let me know and we may add support for this explicitly via the EntityType.setProperties api call.

Comment: option #2 worked great.  thank you for your answer.

entityManager.metadataStore.getEntityTypes().forEach(function(t) { t.concurrencyProperties = []; });